# Creating a component from a plugin's element when plugin is already inside another component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using a third-party plugin and I have no control over it. I'm using Ember in my entire application except for this plugin and I need instantiate a component inside a div rendered by said plugin to control it the way I want (to avoid the use of jQuery events and such).

1- I'm creating a component called "MyNewComponent"

2- The current structure:

```
<myComponent1>
    <myPlugin-notEmber>
       <div-where-I-want-to-append-MyNewComponent class="divClass"/>
    </myPlugin-notEmber>
</myComponent1>
```

3- Take into account that the "div-where-I-want-to-append-MyNewComponent" is rendered by the plugin, not by me.

4- What I'm currently trying to do inside myComponent1 is:

```
onDidInsertElement: Em.on('didInsertElement', function() {
    this.$().find('.divClass').each(function(index, element) {
        MyNewComponent.create().appendTo(Em.$(element));
    });
}),
```

**Why it's not working:**

I'm getting this: (Ember 1.13)

"You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead."

**What I'm looking for:**

a) the right way to do this OR

b) an equivalent alternative (that will create a component inside that plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to use [ember-wormhole](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole)

Which allows you to place anything inside another div with an id, so:

```
{{#ember-wormhole to="destination"}}
  {{my-new-component}}
{{/ember-wormhole}}
```

And somewhere else you'd have

```
<div id="destination"></div>
```

This will render the `{{my-new-component}}` inside of that div.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Yes, it did work. Ember wormhole is perfect for solving this kind of problem. It also keeps all bindings.